# IPSEC tunnel lan to lan with VPS in the middle

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, tunnel

I have an ipsec tunnel between two points with different static public ips, when the tunnel is stablished, each machine see the others with the private ip.

The issue is that I want to put a VPS in the middle, so I want to connect the A point with the B point with the traffic going through the VPS, but I cannot do it at all.

The ipsec is a must hav, because is a black box that works like that so I cannot use openvpn.

A <———->VPS<———->B

Any clue in how to do it?

Comment: Your VPS would have to compatible with and break into the IPsec Tunnel (encrypted Tunnel).

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I do not think you can break into an encrypted site to site IPsec tunnel with VPS unless your VPS supports such a thing.

Comment: I just want to passthrough, I am not interested in seeing what inside the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite certain you cannot do what you are trying to do.

A site to site IPsec tunnel is a straight through encrypted tunnel

You can set up a star config with IPsec endpoints at the star endpoints but each line a straight through line to its relevant endpoint.

You have to break the tunnel and put IPsec connections (2) in the virtual server.

I am not even sure you can do this.

Some reference material for you.

[VPS tutorial](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/beginners-guide-vps/)